# Having trouble creating a 'selection bar'

Tags: css, http

I want to create a navigation bar from `enter code here` left to right that would display options such as sign in, home, etc.  Any help would be great, and thanks for reviewing my problem.

http code:

http://pastebin.com/Dxpii18G

css code:

```
html,body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this, but the key is setting the elements displays to 'inline' or 'inline-block'.  If you are using spans (not recommended) they are inline already.  Most people use the following, as far as I know:

```
<ul>
    <li class="MenuItem">Sign In</li>
    <li class="MenuItem">Home</li>
    <li class="MenuItem">Etc.</li>
</ul>
```

CSS would be:

```
.MenuItem
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That's the idea.